# Alert для Scene

Tags: swift

Нашла как делать Alert для View. А как сделать для Scene?

Вот для View:

```html
var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refresh", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
  println("Handle Ok logic here")
  }))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
  println("Handle Cancel Logic here")
  }))

presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152621/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-from-skscene

Comment: Спасибо за полезную ссылку)) Вопрос решила

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо  `presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)`
нужно так написать:

```
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```